# Jira Agile - Version Report - Predicted Completion Date not showing

Tags: report, version, jira

Capturing the incidents being done in the scrum board (JIRA v7.3.4)

1. Release version was created in Jan'19 only with "Start date" and not "Release date"
2. Story Point estimation was completed for user stories in Jan'19 summing up to around 150 Story points
3. Today (26th Feb'19) following actions were taken

Story Point estimation completed for the remaining user stories summing up to 90 Story points
Release date updated to 31st May'19
4. Prior to today (26th Feb'19) , user stories summing up to 25 story points were done

5. Which is 10% more than the Total story points - 150 + 90 = 240

I'm clueless still why still the predicted date  is not visible. Is it because of the above changes are done today and mostly it will be visible tomorrow, due to some backend process being done by JIRA in the night

Any help would be highly appreciated

Attaching the Pics for reference, some data I have masked for Privacy reasons

[image: Version Report]

[image: Jira Issues attached Version[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipxcY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Post doing the below step Jira is doing the expected

The Version Report is based on your board's column mapping. An issue is considered to be 'To Do' when it is in a status that has been mapped to the left-most column of your board. Similarly, an issue is considered to be 'Done' when it is in a status that has been mapped to the right-most column of your board. See Configuring columns for more information.

reference - [Jira Agile - Version Report - Predicted Completion Date not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886235/jira-agile-version-report-predicted-completion-date-not-showing)